# Routing error. Rendering using get instead of put... Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have the following code:

**tasks/_form.html.haml**

```
%h3 
    Tasks
%span.form-inline.centered
    = form_for [@activity, @task], remote: true do |f|
        = f.text_field :description, {placeholder: 'Enter task description and click + to create a new task', class: 'input-task'}
        = f.submit "+", class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

**controllers/tasks_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

    flash[:error] = I18n.t "errors.task.generic" if !activity.add_task!(params[:task])    

    @task = activity.tasks.last

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to activity_path(activity) }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**tasks/create.js.erb**

```
$('#incomplete-tasks').append("<%= j render partial: 'task', locals: {task: @task} %>");
```

**tasks/_task.html.haml**

```
%li
    = task.description
    = link_to "Done", activity_task_path(task.activity, task: task), html_options = {method: :put, class: 'pull-right'}
```

The problem that I have is when it tries to use js to render the partial my restful resource `activity_task_path` sends a get method instead of the put method that I am specifying. If I don't use js to render it and i just refresh the browser it works fine. I now get a routing error because I do no have a show page. I don't however need one. I just need it to update my task via a put method. If anybody can shed some light on why this is happening I would appreciate it.

**[EDIT1]**

If you have any questions or need me to add any code or anything else that I can do to help let me know. I really don't understand why this is happening. Thank you.

**[EDIT2]**

```
  def update
    activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    activity.update_task!(params[:task])
    redirect_to activity_path(params[:id])
  end
```

This is my update controller.

**[EDIT3]**

You can find the app online at https://trackit.mlpinit.com to get a better understanding of what I am trying to do.
You can authenticate with a random email address I have confirmation set to 2.days.

**[EDIT4]**

Hopping to make it more clear... Here is the error I get when I add a new task through ajax.

Routing Error

**No route matches**

```
 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks", :task=>#<Task id: 64, description: "lalala", complete: false, created_at: "2012-10-11 19:41:22", updated_at: "2012-10-11 19:41:22", activity_id: 6>, :activity_id=>#<Activity id: 6, title: "Lala", description: "this is lala", created_at: "2012-10-10 18:37:18", updated_at: "2012-10-10 18:37:18", user_id: 2, activity_group_id: nil>}
```

Once again if I don't do this through an ajax call it works ok. My assumption is that the problem takes place because it doesn't understand the put method for some reason...

**[EDIT5]**

**If I take of the link from my _task partial the append happens without any errors. I thought I should mention that**

**[EDIT6]**

I will add a visual walkthrough to make sure that I make myself understood...

I have a task form:

[image: task form]

I enter a task name

[image]

I hit (enter)plus to create it.

I get the following error that is also presented above:

[image]
[image]

If I hit refresh the task was generated ok:

[image]

That is why I believe it has to be in the .js.erb file...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `:post` for create action? Your template is `create.js.erb` but the controller is unclear, I assumed create action, but maybe it is `update`? Also it would be much clearer if you add output of `rake routes | grep task`, so we know the proper routing is in place.

Comment: And one more thing, the path should be `activity_tasks_path(task.activity)` if we are talking about create action.

Comment: @CasualCoder I updated my controller. It is the create action. The create happens properly though. The link that is generated should allow for an updated though. And that doesn't happen. I also added my updated controller there. I need both the activity and the activity task in order to update the task complete attribute

Comment: In `update` you have `Activity.find(params[:id])` but in `create` there is `Activity.find(params[:activity_id])`. So shouldn't it be `Activity.find(params[:activity_id])` in `update`? Activity and tasks are nested resources, right?

Comment: @CasualCoder Yes you are right that didn't make much sense from my part let me change it and I'll follow up if there are any changes.

Comment: @CasualCoder I changed that but it still basically does the same thing. It gives me the same error... It still tries to go to the show page instead of update...

Comment: `activity_task_path(task.activity, task: task)`, that second argument  does not look good ... hmmm, let us try with `activity_task_path(task.activity,task)`

Comment: @CasualCoder Actually I double checked but that doesn't seem to be the problem. If i don't use remote: true and i just refresh the page that link works just fine. I will post a link to the actual application as well. You can take a look maybe it will make more sense what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activity_task_path(task.activity, task: task)
```

activity_task_path expects two id parameters, I think your last is now mixed with the task: task and the post parameters. You also get mixups because of the form_for and trying this method to use 'update' for task. You are providing no data fields.

So I think your solution is:

```
activity_task_path(task.activity, task)
```

Comment: The link works when I don't use ajax. What happens is when I do use ajax my method: :put is not sent... Get replaces it...

Comment: What is the actual html that is generated? You can present that in the javascript as alert box, or use Chrome to identify it with the 'inspect element'. Then you know if the generated html is correct or not.

Comment: The problem is that no actual HTML is generated. If I go in my javascript debugger in network I can see the error. I am not sure why the error happens because I am not trying to access the link yet I am just trying to generate it... But there is a route error that says I don't have a show action. I don't want one though... That's why I am using the put method.

Comment: Then exactly WHEN do you get the routing error? When doing the first post for the form_for?

Comment: The post happens so the error doesn't take place when I do create the task at form_for. I get the error when it is trying to append the task that was just created... I uploaded the actual error as well... I will include a screenshot as well...

Comment: Your answer was right all along. I was just getting another error when I tried it out and I couldn't figure it out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `rake routes | grep task` :

```
  activity_task GET    /activities/:activity_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
                PUT    /activities/:activity_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
```

Then inspect generated link that gives you problem in browser, check if it corresponds with the `update` route and if it has `data-method="put"` attribute.

Ok, I've login in and check it, the generated link is not good:

```
<a href="/activities/17/tasks/17?task=5" class="pull-right" data-method="put" rel="nofollow">Done</a>
```

the `17?task=5` part is messed up, it should be: `/activities/17/tasks/5`.

**[EDIT]**

Change the link:

```
= link_to "Done", activity_task_path(:activity_id => task.activity_id, :id => task.id), html_options = {method: :put, class: 'pull-right'}
```

The routing error shows that under :activity_id there is an object instead of only id, and the `:task` attribute is unnecessary and there should be `:id` with a task id value.

Comment: `activity_task GET    /activities/:activity_id/tasks/:id(.:format)              tasks#show`

`PUT    /activities/:activity_id/tasks/:id(.:format)              tasks#update`

They show up there. The link generated is good. But if I use remote It does not actually append the last task...

Comment: 'If I use remote' you mean like that `= link_to "Done", activity_task_path(task.activity, task: task), html_options = {method: :put, remote: true, class: 'pull-right'}`? So you update it in place like in `create` action? So do the same as there, make update.js.erb template rendered it with your update action and add there js to add task to the proper place (hide it, show it, etc.)

Comment: Not there... I have my remote in tasks/_form.html.haml when I create the task. The task is being created. If i hit refresh it shows on the page. However it is not being displayed... I believe because of this error...

Comment: Ok, so it fails at `"<%= j render partial: 'task', locals: {task: @task} %>"`, have you checked if it will append the link to '#' path ?So to be sure that this is the path generating error?

Comment: If I take that link of it appends without a problem... I am not sure why it generates this error. Even if I would generate a broken link it should still display ... I think... rather strange...

Comment: Yea I just figured it out as well :) I am doing this:
activity_task_path(task.activity, task) and it works. If I do it the way you said it works as well. The problem was that I was specifying what task: should be but not activity and the id of the task was going in place of the id for the activity and the other way around. I need to either specify it for both or not specify it for either. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure that you're loading the Rails unobtrusive javascript driver, **rails.js?** I would make sure the following line is in your **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'
```

And if you're using Rails 3.1 that you include it in **application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Checkout [this](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) if you need more detailed instructions on installing it.

Comment: gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.3'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '2.0.2' These 2 are present...
Also 
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs These are present